# SQL Server - Order of Operations difficulty

Tags: sql, sql-server, parentheses

Trying to figure out how to order this properly to get the expected result.  What I'm looking for is A to be true, and any of B, C, or D to be true also.  Starting_Date and Ending_Date are defined earlier in the code.

1. If I use A && ((B)||(C)||(D)) as it's written below, I get no results returned.
2. If I use A && (B || C || D), which I think is logically identical to the above, also returns no results.
3. If I use A && B || C || D, which I think groups A and B together, I get several thousand results
4. If I put parentheses around the Between statements, I get an error (invalid syntax)
5. 

```
Declare @Starting_Date  date = '2019-01-01'
Declare @Ending_Date    date = '2019-01-31'

Select x
From y   
Where   REPORTING_UNIT = '36B11' --A
                        AND ((Closing_Date          BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date) --B Closing date is between report date range (eg: episode already open before period)
                        OR  (Opening_Date           BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date) --C Opening date is between report date range (eg: episode was opened at some point during the period)
                        OR  (Reverse_Opening_Date   BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date)) --D Reverse opening date is between report date range (eg: episode was closed at some point, then reopened during the period)
```

Expected results:

Year of 1858 is the database's way of say "it isn't closed".  So in this example, all of these would be included except for line #14, which was closed prior to our defined ending date.  Lines 5 & 6 would also be included because the episode was open during the period we are evaluating.

[image]

Edit: Added starting and ending date coded in and some expected results.

Comment: can you add some test data and expected output?

Comment: Your code should just work. If it returns no results, it means that there is no row that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @gh9 - Added some expected results

Comment: @GMB - I understand that conceptually, but there are results which should be returned when I run the where's independent of each other - trying to figure out where the flaw is in my logic.

Comment: @fred will you add the test data or a small subset of it

Comment: @gh9 - I'm not sure what you're asking for if the expected results aren't what you're trying to see?  Can you give me more details?

Comment: @Fred Just keep `REPORTING_UNIT = '36B11' AND Closing_Date          BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date` conditions in the `WHERE` clause and see the results that you get and then add the ÒR` conditions one by one and you may get an idea of why this is happening. Have you tried this already?
Also, after a cursory glance at your data above, logically only row 5 should be included. `BETWEEN` clause will just check the date range and row 5 satisfies that. Help me understand this.

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur After spending some time with it, I was able to figure it out.  It was a logic error in how I put trying to compare the data, just as you suggested.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur Can you post this as an actual answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Fred, just added this as an answer. Great that it was resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep
`REPORTING_UNIT = '36B11' AND Closing_Date BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date` conditions in the `WHERE` clause and see the results that you get and then add the `OR` conditions one by one and you may get an idea of why this is happening. Also, after a cursory glance at your data above, logically only row 5 should be included. `BETWEEN` clause will just check the date range and row 5 satisfies that.

Answer (score 0):

The following, which is your code minus the redundant parentheses inside the OR sequence, should work.

Are you confident about the values of @Starting_Date and @Ending_Date?

```
Select x
From y   
Where   REPORTING_UNIT = '36B11' --A
                        AND (Closing_Date          BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date --B Closing date is between report date range (eg: episode already open before period)
                        OR  Opening_Date           BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date --C Opening date is between report date range (eg: episode was opened at some point during the period)
                        OR  Reverse_Opening_Date   BETWEEN @Starting_Date AND @Ending_Date) --D Reverse opening date is between report date range (eg: episode was closed at some point, then reopened during the period)
```

Comment: Edited the code and added actual start and end date values to see.